# RxAndroid: how to add items to observer

Tags: rx-java

I am facing the following problem:

I have a query that produces and Observable.

```
fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        val disposable = model
            .search(newText).
            .subscribeOn(workerThreadScheduler)
            .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler)
            .subscribe(observer)
}
```

Now, the I would like to emit new items to the observer if the function is called again.

Please any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need a backing property.

```
private val querySubject:Subject<<String>> = PublishSubject.create()

fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
    querySubject.onNext(newText)
    return true
}
fun queryStream:Observable<String>{
   return querySubject
}
```

Now you have a function `queryStream` which will emit all the search texts and will not close.
And you can use this like this:

```
val disposable = queryStream.flatMap(model.search(newText))
            .subscribeOn(workerThreadScheduler)
            .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler)
            .subscribe(observer)
```